# Decrypting SSL traffic from an iOS app using FiddlerCore

Tags: ssl, https, fiddlercore

The titular trio of SSL traffic decryption, iOS app, and FiddlerCore is the holy grail I am trying to reach.

The caveats that are so far my undoing:

1) The certificate must be trusted by the iOS device; if it isn't, Safari for example will prompt you to continue, but a third party app won't do this.

2) The certificate must be generated using the [CertMaker for iOS and Android plugin](http://fiddler2.com/add-ons) - that is to say that the bundled makecert.exe produces certificates which iOS does not trust.

I have achieved the SSL decryption part, and the iOS app part, but only from Fiddler itself (not programmatically with FiddlerCore) because it allows you to use a plugin for certificate duty; you cannot use plugins from FiddlerCore.

My attempted solution to this was to manually specify the certificate used by fiddlercore, and point it towards a .cer previously generated by Fiddler and the ios Certificate Maker plugin. In code it would look like this:

```
FiddlerApplication.oDefaultClientCertificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(@"FiddlerRoot.cer");
FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.DecryptSSL | FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.AllowRemoteClients | ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy);
```

Nevertheless I can't make this fly - it still tries to use makecert.exe and as far as I can tell is just disregarding my manually specified certificate; my understanding of SSL certs is woeful so I am hopeful that at the very least someone can tell me I'm barking up the wrong tree. If someone knows what I can do to get to where I want to be it would be very much appreciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oDefaultClientCertificate` object refers to the certificate that FiddlerCore will attempt to send *to* the server if it demands such a certificate for client-certificate-based Authentication. That object has nothing to do with the server-certificate that Fiddler sends to the iOS *client*.

In order for this scenario to work, you need to use the CertMaker plugin for FiddlerCore. Fortunately, the next build of FiddlerCore will ship with a compatible build of that plugin.

Comment: From the horses mouth! Thank you Mr. Lawrence - I have been enlightened. Do I overstep the mark by asking when we might see the next build?

Comment: Keep an eye on the Fiddler discussion forum; should be out in the next few days. thanks!

Comment: And it works a treat! Just had to make sure that the appropriate DLLs were int the same place as my application and that makecert.exe wasn't. Thank you Mr. Law :)